LMS fitting with R-software
I am trying to fit my data in LMS model using following code.
lms_model <- lms(
  y = data$Reaction_time, 
  x = data$Corrected_Age, 
  families = "BCCG", 
  data = data, 
  k = 2, 
  cent = c(0.4, 2, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90, 98, 99.6),
  calibration = TRUE, 
  trans.x = FALSE, 
  fix.power = NULL, 
  lim.trans = c(0, 1.5), 
  prof = FALSE, 
  step = 0.1, 
  legend = FALSE, 
  mu.df = NULL, 
  sigma.df = NULL, 
  nu.df = NULL, 
  tau.df = NULL, 
  c.crit = 0.01, 
  method.pb = "ML"
)

However, it is continuously throwing me warning message "Error in get(deparse(substitute(y)), envir = as.environment(data)): object 'data$Reaction_time' not found"". Even though the data column name is correct, and R is able to read the data. Can someone help me with this.
How can I fit LMS model for my data?
